# VideoView Causes App to Freeze on Switching URI

Tags: android, freeze, android-videoview

I have a VideoView in android that correctly plays a single video. It handles video fine with respect to muting, looping, etc.

I want to be able to switch between videos, however. To that end, I have two uris. I set the initial video like this:

```
_videoView = findViewById(R.id.video);
_videoView.setVideoURI(firstURI);
_videoView.requestFocus();
_videoView.start();
```

When I press Button2, it switches to the second uri like so:

```
_videoView.setVideoURI(secondURI);
_videoView.start();
```

When I press Button 1, it switches back to the first:

```
_videoView.setVideoURI(firstURI);
_videoView.start();
```

That all works fine, but after switching the uri a few times (sometimes as few as three, sometimes as many as seven; three or four is typical), the app freezes. It simply stops responding. There's no error in the log, nothing on screen, and no memory leak that LeakCanary can find. It simply stops responding and never recovers. This happens every single time.

Is there something wrong with how I'm changing the videos for this VideoView? (And yes, I want to use a VideoView.)

Answer (score 1):

First Check your video is available or not then stop this video.It's better for you
Currently your first video still available in _videoView and you are playing another on same.

```
 if (videoView!=null){ 
_videoView.stopPlayback();  
_videoView.setVideoURI(URL);
_videoView.requestFocus();
_videoView.start();
}else{
_videoView.setVideoURI(URL);
_videoView.requestFocus();
_videoView.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this improved the performance a lot! (Though its still freezes sometimes.) I'm not sure about your else statement, though --- won't it break since videoView is null? Also, I'm not sure why two videos can still be available/playing in the same videoView --- doesn't setting the videoURI essentially replace the src, just like changing the src of an image component would? It's not like there are X images layered on top of a single component if you switch an image's src X times. Why would that be true of videos? Maybe I'm just missing something about it.

Comment: After further testing, it seems to freeze pretty much just the same as before.

Comment: @Elliptica suppose you are playing Video from server so in Videoview it will take time to load stream as per network, it will not work same as you expected with quality and size of video .. I suggest ExoPlayer, here is a good sample for caching, you can use VideoCache or OkHttpDataSource. It will helps you with lot of functions

Comment: I'm actually using videos stored in the `raw` folder of my android app, so there's nothing pulling from server/network. It's self-contained in the app.